# How to sort multi-dimensional array with search option in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have created a search box and on keyup event, I am fetching json_encoded array from other file but what I am facing the problem is. For eg. If I will type "Melbourne" It shows "East Melbourne" and other option before the exact match. I want to show Melbourne first then after east Melbourne, West Melbourne and other options.

I want to sort it with the exact search string.

```
The current array is like:
$response[] = array("category"=>'cat_name',"label"=>'East Melbourne');
$response[] = array("category"=>'cat_name',"label"=>'Melbourne');

Output:
{category: "City", label: "East Melbourne", value: "East Melbourne"}
{category: "City", label: "Melbourne", value: "Melbourne"}
```

Comment: Where is your code which search inside array?

Comment: @Shujaat, Thanks for the reply. Actually, I run an SQL query to fetch the data in ASCENDING ORDER and getting the result as above. Now I want to filter the result as the exact LABEL match.

Comment: Your example display the opposite of what you explain. Must "Melbourne" be before or after "East Melbourne"? Where is your code?

Comment: @Toto -- If a user is typing **Melbourne** keyword, it should show the exact match that is **Melbourne** at the first then after east Melbourne should show.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Php function [levenshtein](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php), to get a measure of how similar your search term is to a given string. For each item in the multi dimensional array, you can calculate the similarity using the levenshtein function. The similarity can be stored in an array along with the original string. The array can then be sorted to get sorted search results. The following code can be used:

```
function GetSortedSearchResults($options, $search_term) {

    $sorted_results = array();
    for ($count = 0; $count < count($options); $count++) {
        $similarity = levenshtein($options["label"], $search_term);
        $sorted_results[$similarity] = $options["label"];
    }

    ksort($sorted_results);

    return array_values($sorted_results);
}
```

Comment: This is just perfect, I got the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

function **searchForId**($id, $array) {foreach ($array as $key => $val) {if ($val['label'] === $id) {return $key;}}return null;}
**$response[] = array("category"=>'cat_name',"label"=>'East Melbourne');$response[] = array("category"=>'cat_name',"label"=>'Melbourne');$response[] = array("category"=>'cat_name',"label"=>'West Melbourne');$id = searchForId('Melbourne', $response);$newArr[]=$response[$id];unset($response[$id]);$newArr1=array_merge($newArr,$response);echo "";print_r($newArr1);exit;**